# c# rename file before ftping

Tags: c#, ftp, rename

How can I rename the file to a timestamp or random unique number before it is actually ftped to the server?

example: if i select C:\taco.pdf  ..... 1321981871.pdf is actually what would be ftp'd to the server.

```
FileInfo toUpload = new FileInfo(this.txtFile.Text);

 FtpWebRequest request =
            (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
            "ftp://192.168.0.186" + "/" + toUpload.Name
            );

 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

request.Credentials =
            new NetworkCredential("myuser","mypassword");

Stream ftpStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream file = File.OpenRead(this.txtFile.Text);

 int length = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        int bytesRead = 0;


        do
        {
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            ftpStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        while (bytesRead != 0);

 file.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want the file *uploaded* with a different name without renaming it locally, couldn't you just change

```
 FtpWebRequest request = 
            (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( 
            "ftp://192.168.0.186" + "/" + toUpload.Name 
            );
```

to

```
 FtpWebRequest request = 
            (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( 
            "ftp://192.168.0.186/whatever file name you want");
```

?

Comment: Thanks! that got it and I added           string extension = toUpload.Extension; to pull the extension and appended it to my new filename.   FtpWebRequest request =
                (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                "ftp://192.168.0.186/" + newfilename + extension
                );

Comment: Click the check mark next to the answer that was most helpful to you. I'd recommend going back and doing so for *all* of your previously asked questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`FileInfo.MoveTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto.aspx):

```
toUpload.MoveTo(newName);
```